# pyqt5 - No query Unable to fetch row

Tags: pyqt5, qsqlquery

I have a problem using QSQLQuery to join two SQLite tables. When I run the program I get the error "No query Unable to fetch row". I can't spot which could be the problem as
executing the same query in SQLiteStudio it works fine.
Below I put the code, the tables structure and the .ui file.
Thanks for any help

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt, QModelIndex
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlTableModel, QSqlRelation, QSqlQuery, QSqlQueryModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableView,QWidget
from quadro_costiUi import Ui_f_riepilogoCosti

class QuadroCosti(QWidget, Ui_f_riepilogoCosti):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        con=QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        con.setConnectOptions("detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES | sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES")
        con.setDatabaseName("/Users/User/Documents/Micro/db/Micro.db")
        con.open()

        query=QSqlQuery()
        query.prepare("SELECT * FROM tb_PreventivoDatiGenerali \
                           INNER JOIN tb_PreventivoDettaglioFasi \
                           ON tb_PreventivoDettaglioFasi = tb_PreventivoDatiGenerali.codicePreventivo \
                           AND tb_PreventivoDettaglioFasi.revisionePreventivo = tb_PreventivoDatiGenerali.revisione")
        query.exec()
        print(query.lastError().text())                   

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QuadroCosti()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

-- SQLite tables --

```
CREATE TABLE tb_PreventivoDatiGenerali (
codicePreventivo INTEGER NOT NULL,
revisione VARCHAR NOT NULL,
nomePreventivo CHAR NOT NULL,
dataPreventivo DATETIME NOT NULL,
flagFasi BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
flagMateriale BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
dataInserimento VARCHAR,
dataModifica VARCHAR,
PRIMARY KEY (
codicePreventivo,
revisione
)
);

CREATE TABLE tb_PreventivoDettaglioFasi (
codicePreventivo INTEGER NOT NULL,
revisionePreventivo VARCHAR,
nomeFase CHAR (255),
internaEsterna CHAR (1),
quantità INTEGER,
PzPerCarico INTEGER,
Campioni INTEGER,
Risorsa STRING (5),
nrCarichi INTEGER,
barraUtile INTEGER,
setupOre REAL,
setupMinuti REAL,
cicloSecondi REAL,
cicloMinuti REAL,
[%scarto] REAL,
[%efficienza] REAL,
[€/h] REAL,
costoPerCarico REAL,
costoCadauno REAL,
costoAggiuntivo REAL,
[%ricarico] REAL,
[€/cadauno] REAL,
[T (h)] REAL,
[LT (gg)] REAL,
desMat CHAR,
quantitàMat INTEGER,
diametroMat REAL,
psMat REAL,
lungPezzoGrezzoMat INTEGER,
[€/KgMat] REAL,
[€/cadaunoMat] REAL,
[LTMat(gg)] REAL,
dataIns VARCHAR,
dataMod VARCHAR,
PRIMARY KEY (
codicePreventivo ASC,
revisionePreventivo,
nomeFase
)
);
```

Comment: Note that since the error is in the query, we don't really need anything else (especially the UI). That said, with the above query, I get `'no such column: tb_PreventivoDettaglioFasi Unable to execute statement'`. Ensure that you're using the correct table and that the provided schema is compliant with the database you're using.

Comment: I think it should be `query.exec_()` (with an underscore (_) after exec). Also there is a problem with your JOIN statement. You're not providing a column name in this code on the left hand side of the = : `ON tb_PreventivoDettaglioFasi = tb_PreventivoDatiGenerali.codicePreventivo`

Comment: @bfris - I tried also with query.exec_() but I get the same error "No query Unable to fetch row". About the JOIN statement I did not get your point: I don't think there's any column name missing as I execute the same statement in SQLiteStudio it works.

Comment: @MDR Of course there's a column name missing. Why do you think makes any sense to compare a table with a column? It clearly should be `tb_PreventivoDettaglioFasi.codicePreventivo = tb_PreventivoDatiGenerali.codicePreventivo` instead. The code statement you're executing in SQLiteStudio is not the same as what you've shown in your question. You must have made a copy/paste error somewhere.

Comment: @ekhumoro - you're totally right, I must have made a mistake during the copy/paste from SQLiteStudio. Sorry for that and thanks for your support